# All possible combinations, with missing items

Tags: combinatorics

I am trying to solve [this problem](https://adventofcode.com/2020/day/10#part2).

The first example states that I need to determine all arrangements of these numbers:

```
(0), 1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 10, 11, 12, 15, 16, 19, (22)
```

**Where the following items can be missing**: `5, 6, 11`

From what I can tell, the missing combinations can be expressed as:

```
[ ]              0 0 0
5 6 11           1 1 1
5 6              1 1 0
    11           0 0 1
5                1 0 0
  6              0 1 0
5   11           1 0 1
  6 11           0 1 1
```

So, this is basically `2^n` i.e. `2^8` combinations.

However, for the second example:

```
(0), 1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 14, 17, 18, 19, 20, 23, 24, 25, 28, 31,
32, 33, 34, 35, 38, 39, 42, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, (52)
```

Where the following items can be missing:

```
 1, 2, 8, 9, 18, 19, 24, 32, 33, 46, 47
```

The bit approach states that the solution is `2^11 = 2,048`.

But, the solution is stated as `19,208` distinct arrangements.

What am I missing?

Comment: If I go by your first example, there are $13$ items. $10$ of them need to be there in the arrangements whereas other $3$ may be there or may not be there. Is that correct interpretation?

Comment: Just went through your link. It seems a bit of a different problem than how you have presented here. I would suggest you frame your question here such that it is complete, even without reference to the link.

Comment: You are solving a completely different problem to the page you link to (which seems to just want you to sort a list and look at the gaps between numbers).

Comment: As for what you are asking for, I assume the problem is actually not as you describe, but that the task is to count the subsets of the given set of numbers such that no gap is more than 3. In that case, could you not include 2 and 4  but skip over 3? Or skip over 10 by including 8 and 11?

Comment: Guys, you are right, I missed the logic of it. I will delete the question since it's completely wrong. Maybe you can give me some help before I delete it? As @JaapScherphuis said, the problem is `to count the subsets of the given set of numbers such that no gap is more than 3. In that case, could you not include 2 and 4 but skip over 3? Or skip over 10 by including 8 and 11?`

Comment: Use dynamic programming. If the given list is $a_1, ... a_n$, and suppose you have already figured out the answers for all the shorter lists $a_1, ... a_m$ with $m<n$, can you use those answers to calculate the answer for the full list?